# Using Paper.js to highlight a region of interest in a youtube video

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, youtube, paperjs

I'm trying to use Paper.js to build a tool that allows an user to select a region of interest within a video in their browser. This example reflects what I'm trying to accomplish: http://paperjs.org/examples/hit-testing/

Picture the user being able to create a blob around a portion of a youtube video to highlight a person. I then plan to use the coordinates from the points of the blob for some computer vision processing based on the interest of the user.

I think Paper.js is a great tool for this purpose, however, I'm having a hard time embedding a Youtube video inside a canvas element so that I can actually use Paper.js to build the tool. It's been surprisingly hard to find information on how I can accomplish this - this stackoverflow question provides an answer, but the youtube video must be downloaded rather than simply linked through its URL: [Youtube video Inside canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28106909/youtube-video-inside-canvas)

Am I approaching this task correctly? Can anyone think of a way to accomplish this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not figure how to embed the youtube video inside the canvas, but I managed to do exactly what I wanted placing the youtube video behind the Canvas element! It turns out that a canvas is transparent, so all it took was some CSS to accomplish what I wanted. However, this disables the controls of the video, you will need to write some javascript for that to work. The following link explains how to place a video behind a canvas: https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/HTML-canvas-guide/PuttingVideoonCanvas/PuttingVideoonCanvas.html